# How to delete a particular row properly using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need one help.I need to remove a particular row from a table using Angular.js .Here i have `+` and `-` button implementation.I have all my code inside https://plnkr.co/edit/D3UrDYwiglMKQyCW0wvW?p=preview

From the Plunkr suppose for Monday i did 3 entries using `+` button.when i am deleting the middle(second) row using `-` button this is deleting but it doing null to the 3rd row subcategory field and also displaying the different subcategory which is not belongs to that row category part.Here i need when user will delete any row that row value will delete not other row.All codes are present inside [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/D3UrDYwiglMKQyCW0wvW?p=preview).Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zs3IDssfE7wqcr1JWZKm?p=preview)

Some of the changes:

1. Defined listOfSubCategory in the controller as an array rather than having a function build it for each category.

**Controller**:

```
$scope.listOfSubCategory = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'SubCategory 1',
  value: 1,
  category: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'SubCategory 2',
  value: 2,
  category: 2
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'SubCategory 3',
  value: 3,
  category: 3
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'SubCategory 4',
  value: 4,
  category: 4
}];
```

2. Changed ng-options to filter the subcategories based on selected category.

**HTML**

```
ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCategory | filter:{ category: answer.category.id}"
```

3. Also, made some other minor changes, like having only on  for all 's rather than one for each  and used "track by $index" where needed.

Comment: it seems its working in plunkr.let me to implement this in my project and will update u.

Comment: Ok.  Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: yes,now i am out of office.will implement later.in my project there are so many db operation ,i will implement there and inform u.

Comment: Your table structure are not aligned properly check it.

Comment: @ jbrown: `$scope.listOfSubCategory` is a object which contain the sub-category value from DB and u have defined this before.I can not understand this.

Comment: :No,Your answer is not working as per my requirement.You can check my plunkr also.

Comment: Yes, I see the alignment issue with the table structure.  The changes I made were to eliminate the multiple usages of ng-repeat.  I didn't spend the time to fix the formatting issue that resulted.  Its been a long time since I've used tables since most modern pages are responsive and rely on CSS for layout rather than tables.

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways of accomplishing what you are trying to do but my approach would be to get $scope.listOfSubCategory  into a structure like the one I've hardcoded.  I know your data is coming from the db but I would manipulate that data in js to be similar to my example rather than try manage it in html where it is hard to code, understand, and debug.